# Почему не работает password_verify()

Tags: php

столкнулся с ситауацией, что не прозодит проверка пароля

```
 $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password = md5($password);
        $sql ="SELECT * FROM users WHERE usr ='$username'";
        $stmt =sqlsrv_query($conndev,$sql) or die(print_r(sqlsrv_query()));
        $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC); 
        if (!$row) 
        {
            echo '<p class="error">Неверные пароль или имя пользователя!</p>';
        }else 
        {
        var_dump($password);
        var_dump($row['pass']);         
            $pas_check = password_verify($password, $row['pass']);
            var_dump($pas_check);
            if ($pas_check == true) {
                echo '<p class="success">Поздравляем, вы прошли авторизацию!</p>';
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['id'];           
            }
            else
            {
                echo '<p class="success">Пароль не верный</p>';
            }
```

Вот что выводит ВарДамп :
string(32) "1844156d4166d94387f1a4ad031ca5fa"
string(32) "1844156d4166d94387f1a4ad031ca5fa"
bool(false)
Хотя пароли идентичные, в чем может быть проблема? Или сделать явную проверку , без password_verify? Насколько это будет безопасно?

Comment: @PeterKolosov я так понял ,мне не нужно хэшировать вводимый пароль, а проверять его уже с хэшированным в БД, верно?

Comment: то было не то. `password_verify` НЕ сравнивает одно с другим, а: сначала хэширует первый аргумент, потом проверяет на соответствие с вторым аргументом.

Comment: @PeterKolosov , окей, понял в каком месте я затупил, но собсвтенно проблема не решилась, если сделать вот так: 'echo md5($password);
  var_dump($password);
  var_dump($row['pass']);   
   $pas_check = password_verify($password, $row['pass']);
   var_dump($pas_check);' c выводом захешированного пароля, всё равно  password_verify возвращает false

Comment: А так работает?

Comment: Буду рад если вы ещё проголосуете вверх, спасибо)

Comment: Даже если там уже есть голоса

Comment: @PeterKolosov, да всё работает, спасибо, я проголовал, мне не сложно , но :  "Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга."

Comment: Теперь можете )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, вам нужно делать простую проверку.

В [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) написано, что функция `password_verify`

> Verifies that the given hash matches the given password.

То есть это не то, что вам нужно. Просто проверяйте вместо

```php
$pas_check = password_verify($password, $row['pass']);
```

это

```php
$pas_check = $password === $row['pass'];
```

**Переменную** `$password` **изменять не нужно.**

Comment: я разобрался - я МД5 пытался рахеширвоать, а по вашей ссылке там штатное хеширвоание нужно использовать, спасибо